# how to run multiple background process in a button

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am having a problem. I am new in c#. In this code when I click the button2, it will  run `bgutures.RunWorkerAsync();` only. But I need to modify it such like  if I click on `button2`, all items the `checkedListBox1.allitems` contains are download, one by one in bgworker.  Can anyone please help  in this.
My code is :

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Enabled = false;
        string DayAtoZ = " ";
        string DayDead = " ";
        string Dayutures = " ";
        string Daysify = " ";
        string Dayfx = " ";

        if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == "")
        {

        }
        else if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == Dayutures)
        {


        }
        else if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == DayAtoZ)
        {

        }

        else if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == Daysify)
        {

        }
        else if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == DayDead)
        {

        }
        else if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == Dayfx)
        {

        }

        {
            bgutures.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        {
            bgDead.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        {
            bgsify.RunWorkerAsync();
        }



        {
            bgAtoZ.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        {

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of one `BackgoundWorker` use as many as your need.

```
    if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == "")
    {
       var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
       .. do setup
       worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    else if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem == Dayutures)
    {
       var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
       .. do setup
       worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Hi , sir  ..do setup   means , what i need to modify here , can please add in my code what i need chnage . because i am new in c#

Comment: this is not working  can u please change  this  ,or add in mycode,